# Node.js Promise.all() hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Kind of stuck on this one. Working with https://github.com/then/promise on node.js

```
exports.count = function ( models, callback ) {
  var promises = [];

  models.forEach(function ( name ) {
    promises.push( countOne( name ) );
  });

  Promise.all( promises ).then(function ( res ) {
    callback( null, res );
  });

  Promise.resolve(promises[0]).then(function (res) {
    console.log('resolved individual with res', res);
  });
};

function countOne ( exampleArg ) {
  return new Promise(function ( resolve, reject ) {
    // It resolves or rejects
  });
}
```

I've also tried:

```
Promise.all( promises.map(function ( it ) { return Promise.resolve(it); }) ).then(function ( res ) {
  callback( null, res );
});
```

Either way, Promise.all doesn't fire the then. Promise.resolve does, however, give the appropriate response.

Comment: One (or more) of your promises in the `.all` isn't resolving and none are rejecting (and it's not `promises[0]`. So that's that.

Comment: this would be a lot cleaner if you just return the promise instead of using a callback, you also arn't propagating error's now

Comment: The 1st callback to `.then()` is only for *fulfillment* (all resolved). You haven't provided anything to be done upon rejection, so it'll fail silently.

Comment: Oh yeah, one of them might actually be rejecting, I forgot `then` promises don't even detect unhandled exceptions like Bluebird promises or native promises in Firefox do.

Comment: Add a `onRejected` handler to your `then` statement. I'm pretty confident that your promises are completing from the give code, so it must be one of more of the promises rejecting.

Comment: Always reject with proper `Error`s for stack traces, prefer using `throw` to using `reject()` when possible (like in this case)

Comment: I love how you gave me that `-_-` - clearly you understand this topic better than me and I should back off, happy coding and good luck.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I feel like the `-_-` expresses misunderstanding and confusion and not really contempt.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I stand corrected

Comment: In any event: @James_1x0 You want to reject with an `Error` because then you can log out a stack trace, referring to exact file and line where the `Error` occurred. You could say that rejecting a promise is the `async` equivalent of throwing an `Error`

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer: I figured it out, but I'm really unsure how to rephrase the entire question. `connection.model` was rejecting the promise for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ether one of your promises isn't resolving, in which case, your need to find out which one.

I think you are trying to do that with that `console.log`. if you do that with a forEach you can attach a log message to all promises and see which one isn't resolving / rejecting.

Or one of the promises is rejecting, which you are not handling.

I took the liberty of rewriting your code, try it like this:

```
exports.count = function (models, callback) {
    var allCounts = models.map(countOne);

    // second parameter is the onRejected handler
    Promise.all(allCounts).then(function (res) {
        callback(null, res);
    }, function (err) {
        callback(err);
    });

    promises[0].then(function (res) {
        console.log('resolved individual with res', res);
    });
};
```

I left in the callback, but I really would just return the promise, much simpler, much cleaner.

ProTip™:
Switch to the [bluebird promise library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), and replace your implementation with one line:

```
exports.count = function (models, callback) {
    Promise.map(models, countOne).nodeify(callback);
}
```

It will probably be faster to.

Comment: In Bluebird, this whole code would be `Promise.map(models).nodeify(callback)` although mixing callbacks is silly here.

Comment: Surely, to rewrite someone's code in this forum is not to take a liberty. Is rewriting code not, pragmatically speaking, the *raison d'être* of StackOverflow?